# Verilog macro to check if in simulation or synthesis

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I need to modify the behavior of my design sources to do something slightly different in simulation and synthesis (I need to zero out a timestamp in simulation to get deterministic results.)  Is there a verilog macro defined so I can tell in which mode the source is being used?   Something like...

```
`ifdef __SYNTHESIS__
   timestamp <= hardware_ts;
`else
   timestamp <= 0;
`endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be very tool specific. Simulators from Mentor define `MODEL_TECH` and `QUESTA` macros

You are better off defining the macro yourself with `+define+__SYNTHESIS__` when running any synthesis tool on the command line.

Comment: Where does +define+__SYNTHESIS__ go?

Comment: On the tool command line

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a parameter to each module that passes down whether you're in synthesis or simulation mode.  Just make the default value the one needed for proper synthesis and you won't have to do anything special unless you're instantiating from the test bench.

Also useful for things like HOW_MANY_CLOCK_CYCLES_TO_WAIT_FOR_PLL_TO_LOCK, which will be quite different in synthesis/reality (depends how long you'd like to wait for it in simulation).

Comment: You mean parameter as in VHDL generic equivalent in SV?

Comment: Do you mean that, we have parameter at top level with default values? The default are used during synthesis and the assigned value is used when we instantiate the module in testbench and assign value to the parameter there?

Comment: @gyuunyuu yes to both questions